# How to continue Debian installation after comparing config files?

Tags: debian, debian-bullseye

Noob question here. I'm updating Debian from Buster to Bullseye. A configuration file change question popped up and I choose to compare the 2 files. Now, how do I get out of the compare option and continue the installation?

[image: compare configuration file change]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961025/how-do-i-exit-the-systemctl-status-commands-output).

It appears this was a status output command, which can be ended with `q`